# Can I watch website video with Silverlight based player on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, kodi, web

I recently got my hands on the new raspberry pi 2. So far I'm enjoying my experience with Kodi (using OSMC).

Among the projects I want to accomplish with this device, is a way to access this website (https://beinsportsconnect.net).  It is the official website for being sports and if you have an account, you can stream HD quality channels 24/7. Unfortunately, this website uses Silverlight, which I assume - from what I researched - is going to be problematic. If it is worth mentioning they also have an app in the Google Play store.

My question is if there is any hints you think can guide me to make this happen using any available OS (using Kodi or Linux it doesn't matter) for the pi.

Comment: At least for some services (like Netflix) Android Pi or Chrome OS might be (or may will be) an option. [Click here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/434/is-there-any-workaround-for-netflix-compatibility) for more infos.

Comment: You can buy an extra codec to get the video stream used in Silverlight to use hardware codecs. But the problem is the DRM. Maybe install the Google App on an Android, then see if you can sniff the URL the video is comming from. You may be lucky to somehow do a man in the middle HTTPS sniffing but I dont think Android supports Silverlight.. so they must be using another stream somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does not run the RaspberryPi , there is nothing you can do about it. The Moonlight project (for Silverlight on Linux) never supported DRM and has no hardware-acceleration either.

Both technologies have been abandoned by their authors too.

Furthermore no Android builds are hardware-accelerated , stable or even Google 
"certified" which might be needed for DRM support.