# How can I watch Netflix on the Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, streaming-video, osmc

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and I would like to set it up so that I can use my Netflix subscription to watch on the TV it's hooked up to.

I've seen that OSMC has support for Netflix but that it's currently limited to Raspberry Pi 3 and older models.

Is there an alternative that I can use to watch Netflix on my Raspberry Pi 4?

I've also seen posts about a [Netflix plugin](https://github.com/CastagnaIT/plugin.video.netflix/) for Kodi that might be used on Raspberry Pi 4 when running LibreELEC. Is that a viable option?

Comment: OSMC doesn't support pi4 after one year!! Try switching to libreelec - or install raspbian and add KODI

Comment: You will need Kodi to be installed. https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-netflix/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to watch Netflix quite nicely on my Raspberry Pi 4 by installing [LibreELEC OS](https://libreelec.tv/) OS (Leia 9.2.1) on it and adding the [CastagnalIT Netflix plugin for Kodi](https://github.com/CastagnaIT/plugin.video.netflix/) on top of that.

If I understand correctly, the plug-in is indeed based on the technique that @dmitry-grigoryev mentions in his answer.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it's [possible](https://blog.vpetkov.net/2019/07/12/netflix-and-spotify-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-with-latest-default-chromium/) to get Netflix working in Chromium in Raspbian OS, if you manage to rip the DRM library out of ChromeOS. I haven't tried it myself, but [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100838/33476) user seems to have succeeded on a Pi 3. I don't see why Pi 4 would be different.

Comment: `I don't see why Pi 4 would be different.` OP uses OSMC and that does not yet support the Pi4. That's why that solution is limited to Pi3-

Comment: @Dirk I'm talking about running Chromium on **Raspbian**, not OSMC.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a 1-line-paste solution to this, in case it's helpful for anyone:

https://blog.vpetkov.net/2020/03/30/raspberry-pi-netflix-one-line-easy-install-along-with-hulu-amazon-prime-disney-plus-hbo-spotify-pandora-and-many-others/

It essentially comes down to:

1.) Having the latest Raspbian installed
2.) Running:

```
curl -fsSL https://pi.vpetkov.net -o ventz-media-pi
sh ventz-media-pi
```

3.) Rebooting and then going to the Application Menu (top left) -> go to “Internet” -> open “Chromium (Media Edition)”

Enjoy.

Comment: This. Is. Awesome. (works great on my pi4)

Comment: @Ventz I tried to install it on my Raspberry Pi 4 (8 GB) with Ubuntu Mate 20.10 and although I see the Media Edition installed, it doesn't seem to work, I'm still getting an error message from Netflix

Comment: I’ve only tested it on Raspian (Raspberry Pi OS). It does not work on 64bit (due to Google - both Chromium and libwidevine are 32bit only for arm). 

You may be able to manually “port” for Ubuntu on the Pi, but I haven’t tried it. It should be easy to check- drop latest lib and launch Chromium with the correct user agent from the ventz-media-pi scripts.