# Is there anything to prevent Android running on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: operating-systems, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56/can-i-install-android)

It doesn't appear in the list of OSs known to run on RPi. But it would be great to see an inexpensive Android tablet using this device.

Most Android tablets would appear to run on ARM chips, so should be possible.

Comment: See [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56/can-i-install-android)

Comment: Exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Technically there isn't. You can try to install Android no matter that it isn't listed like a supported device. Note that the new versions of Android have bigger CPU and RAM requirements.

But, Android is a Java mobile platform that targets phones and tablets. It is made for touch enabled devices. In the Raspberry Pi case, unless you extend it with a touch enabled monitor you will have a very poor user experience.